# Auto-encoder design tips

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

When training a stacked auto-encoder, what are the best practices to choose the number of hidden layers, and their sizes?

For example, is it best to set the hidden layer size to be one minus the input layer size, in each layer of the stack?

Also, does one need to perform hyper-parameter optimization (e.g. L2 Weight Regularization) at each layer in the stack, or do the hyper-parameters from one location in the stack tend to generalize well for others?

Comment: There is no answer for this without knowing the data and even when known the theory of this is not well understood. And no, they don't necessarily tend to generalize well.

Comment: I see - good to know. Thanks,